# $(X,\sigma(\mathcal{G}))$ being a measurable space implies that $X\subseteq \mathcal{G}$?

Tags: measure-theory

While reading my textbook came upon this expression:

> "Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space, and let $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(\mathcal{G})$ (i.e. the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{G}$)"

In this case what can we say about $X$ and $\mathcal{G}$? I am inclined to think that $X\subseteq \mathcal{G}$, because otherwise $\mathcal{A}$ wouldn't be a sigma algebra on $X$.

Am I right?

Comment: $\mathcal G\subseteq\mathcal P(X)$, since $\sigma(\mathcal G)$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\mathcal G$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not need to be the case. Pick $\mathcal{G}=\emptyset$, then (for $X\neq \emptyset$) $X \nsubseteq\emptyset =\mathcal{G}$.

The only thing we know is $\mathcal{G}\in \mathcal{P} (X)$. That is because for any $\mathcal{G}\in \mathcal{P}(X)$ we get a measure space $(X, \sigma(\mathcal{G}))$.

Comment: Good point (+1), but is there anything else we can conclude about $X$ and $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: I am afraid the only thing we know is what Alessandro Codenotti already said in his comment.

Comment: But, if we pick $\mathcal{G}=\emptyset$, is $(X,\sigma(\emptyset))$ still a measurable space??

Comment: @RScrlli Sure, then $\mathcal{A}= \{\emptyset,X\}$ which is a valid choice.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma makes sense! Kinda abstract ideas to deal with without a piece of paper and a pencil. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

I think the textbook wants to talk about a generating set (base) for the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and so in particular $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$. That's about all we know.